# I can't sort dataTable in primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, sorting, primefaces, datatable

I want to sort a dataTable in primefaces 3.5. When I click on the column header - it seems to be clicked clicked (the background and the arrow changes its colour) - but the table is not sorting. Here's my code:

Bean (I also tried putting the code from @PostConstruct to the constructor, but then I get NullPointerException):

```
package view;

import entity.Klient;
import facade.KlientFacade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import static util.Messages.addFlashMessage;

@Named(value = "manageClient")
@Dependent
@ViewScoped
public class ManageClient implements Serializable {

    private List<Klient> clientList;
    @EJB
    private KlientFacade klientFacade;

    public List<Klient> returnClientList(){
        return getKlientFacade().findAll();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        clientList = returnClientList();
    }

    public ManageClient() {

    }

    public String removeClient(Klient klient){
        addFlashMessage("Klient ["+klient.getLogin()+"] został usunięty.");
        getKlientFacade().remove(klient);
        return "manage";
    }

    public List<Klient> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }

    public void setClientList(List<Klient> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }

    public KlientFacade getKlientFacade() {
        return klientFacade;
    }

    public void setKlientFacade(KlientFacade klientFacade) {
        this.klientFacade = klientFacade;
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable paginator="true" rows="10" var="klient" value="#{manageClient.clientList}">
                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.idKlienta}" headerText="ID">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.idKlienta}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.imie}" headerText="Imię">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.imie}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.nazwisko}" headerText="Nazwisko">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.nazwisko}" />
                            </p:column>  

                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.login}" headerText="Login">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.login}" />
                            </p:column>  

                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.haslo}" headerText="Hasło">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.haslo}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{klient.idTypu.typ}" headerText="Typ">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{klient.idTypu.typ}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Usuń">  
                                <h:commandButton value="Usuń" action="#{manageClient.removeClient(klient)}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

**EDIT:**
When I put the code from @PostConstruct to the constructor, I get NullPointerException, stack trace:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: view.ManageClient.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:157)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:176)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.ManageClient.returnClientList(ManageClient.java:31)
    at view.ManageClient.<init>(ManageClient.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Check if your `KlientFacade` is `null` or not. And you don't need to create a new `ArrayList` in your `init` method if you assign immediatelly afterwards another `List` to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your problem in order to get a compilable and testable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example which works perfectly for me and runs in a basic servlet container (Mojarra JSF impl 2.1.25, Primefaces 3.5 and Tomcat 7). I changed some of your annotations because I don't have a Java EE container or CDI available. That's what works for me:

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable paginator="true" rows="10" var="klient"
                value="#{manageClient.clientList}">

                <p:column sortBy="#{klient.imie}" headerText="Imię">
                    <h:outputText value="#{klient.imie}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{klient.login}" headerText="Login">
                    <h:outputText value="#{klient.login}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**ManageClient.java**

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManageClient implements Serializable {

    //Created my own Klient class which only has two properties
    public class Klient {
        private String imie;

        private String login;

        public String getImie() {
            return imie;
        }

        public void setImie(String imie) {
            this.imie = imie;
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }

        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }
    }

    private List<Klient> clientList;

    public List<Klient> returnClientList() {
        //changed your data access object by my own list
        Klient k = new Klient();
        k.setImie("imi1");
        k.setLogin("log1");
        Klient k2 = new Klient();
        k2.setImie("-imi1");
        k2.setLogin("-log1");
        return Arrays.asList(k, k2);

    }

    public ManageClient() {
        clientList = new ArrayList<Klient>();
        clientList = returnClientList();
    }

    public String removeClient(Klient klient) {
        return "manage";
    }

    public List<Klient> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }

    public void setClientList(List<Klient> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }
}
```

Which basically suggests the problem is not about Primefaces in this case. I tested it with latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE. If you're working with previous versions that could be the problem, [Primefaces 3.5 is no longer supporting IE 7](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2408) for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the snippet. It works as I create static list (just like you did in returnClientList() ). But when I put "return getKlientFacade().findAll();" instead - I get "Cant instantiate class: view.ManageClient." - there's a NullPointerException in stacktrace. I just want to download the list from the DB.
btw. why did you create a Klient class in ManageClient class? What's   the purpose?

Comment: Just to provide a Runnable example in a single class. By the way, the exception you're getting is surely because a null pointer in your constructor, if you update your question with the stack trace maybe I'll be able to help.

Comment: Just debug your constructor and post construct methods. See what happens and check that data is loading properly from the DB. Probably your klient facade is not being injected or you're accessing some `null` variable inside there.